# Connecting monitors in different rooms to same computer without Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, external-display, workspace, mac-pro

I'm considering a Mac Pro. I spend a lot of time on my computer as my career is programming and my hobby is music production. My music production equipment is one one room, my work office is in another room. This is by design to keep my work and play separated.

I'm in a situation where I do not have a good music production machine, and can't justify spending 5k+ on a hobby machine alone. I use my 2016 MacBook Pro, attached to 2 external monitors, for my work right now and I'm pushing this machine to its limits on a daily basis. I'd like something more powerful.

I would love to buy a Mac Pro and be able to use it from either room **without remoting into the machine**.

**Problem**

I have one computer and would like to use it in two rooms without moving it around or switching plugs. However, I think the only solution is to use a Remote Desktop to accomplish this. I'd like to have a direct connection to the machine from both rooms.

**Question**

Is this "switchable" workspace scenario possible without using Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a bit speculative…

I doubt you could do all this latency-free over the air. You'd probably want a good part of this wired.

A Bluetooth mouse/keyboard would allow you to reach from both rooms [even if you simplified by carrying them with you].
I have a Logitech keyboard with built-in trackpad on my living room [HTPC] Mac Pro so I can control it from the sofa. I use a 10m USB extension cable so I can get the BT dongle in a better position to pick up well from anywhere in the room.
I actually deal with almost everything else on that Mac over Remote Desktop, but a lot of that is because I hate trackpads so do all the fiddly stuff from my main Mac & just use the living room one for playback.

To avoid latency, you'd have to push video by wire. idk how far modern TB3/HDMI video will push but 15m was too far for my old Mac Pro. 10m over DVI was as far as I could push it before the picture started to degrade.

You then get the issue of which screen anything appears on. Setting 'Displays have separate Spaces' in Mission Control prefs may help you with that. If something is on the wrong Space you could swap to it from either room/screen.

Audio could be manually switchable between output devices, just from the Sound or Audio MIDI Setup control panel, or getting tricksy with something like [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/). Screen or small speakers for the work room, push to your audio DAC for music, again over longer USB cabling. You can buy USB cables with in-line re-transmission to 30m. I have one that long for my camera tethering. [Random google search for one such cable supplier, with explanation](http://www.yourcablestore.com/USB-Cable-Length-Limitations-And-How-To-Break-Them_ep_42-1.html)

You *could* push audio & video OTA these days, but you'd need an Apple TV or similar to receive it & you'd get too much latency for an audio workstation. I've never tried ASIO on an OTA connection, but I doubt it would be much fun ;)